# How do I get server to recognize html tag on index instead of htm?

Tags: html, .htaccess

Trying to upload a new site and the server isn't configured to resolve "html" rather than "htm" so I get the following message:

Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

How can I reconfigure the server as opposed to renaming all the site files?

seems like an .htaccess file might be the answer but I can't find and/or remember what the syntax is that you put into it.

Comment: @j08691: Not a duplicate. That question is about setting directory default index pages; this is about adding MIME types.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do it: add the type to your root .htaccess file.

```
AddType text/html html
```

So: adds the MIME type `text/html` to files with extension `html`.

Hope this helps.